# Time distribution to take rest each day

Tags: halal-haram, sunnah, time

Is there some limitation for Moslem to take a while to rest on each day 
may be 4 hours or some thing
that said by verse or sunnah??

I want to use my time properly since my live seem not efficient as possible.

Answer (score 1):

In al-asr god is talking about the time.
he said we are in loss and he's right we lose most of our time. There's no limitation but any time you are doing something just Not for god you are in loss even if you are doing something studying working or even fighting in a war unless is for Allah.

everything you do for your self is a loss. why? Because you just giving the results of your tries just in this world but if you even sleep study work fight for god you will receive the results in both worlds.

Think of a fighter who fight just for taking care of his country and be killed?  Yes he will give the result his country will be saved for who will stay alive but what's the result he gave his life for a mortal reason :) but if you go to work for god and be killed by a bus you will be considered Shahid because you was in the way of doing something for god.

Quality matters my bro.

Comment: +!. ah.. deeds matter by will.. yeah, God's will.. But I still need more spirit for now..